# Jquery accordian with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  am trying to below code but not get proper output

Errors:

1. accordion must collapse first
2. one accordion click is closing and expanding all at once, that's wrong.. Each accordion should open and close corresponding table
3. 10 Parent row with inner data

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <table id="dataTable"class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr><th scope="col">item</th>
                <th scope="col">vendor</th>
                <th scope="col">Vendor Location</th>
                <th scope="col">BU</th>
                <th scope="col">Min Cost</th>
                <th scope="col">Avg Cost&nbsp;</th>
                <th scope="col">Max Cost&nbsp;</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Quantity Sold</th></tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="pg-margin-auto">
    <nav>
            <ul class="pagination">
            </ul>
          </nav>
          </div>    
</div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
$(".table thead").css({"background":"#616264"});
$("#innertable thead").css({"background":"#616264 "});
$('th').css({"color":"#ffffff"});
$(".pagination").css({"margin-left":"200px"});
$("td").css({"display":"flex","justify-content":"space-between","margin-bottom":"25px"})
$("table").css({"border":"0","border-collapse":"separate", "border-spacing":"0 10px","margin-top":"0px","margin-bottom":"0px"});
$("td[colspan=8]").css({"padding":"0"});
$(".container").css({"background":"#f2f2f2"});
$("td[colspan=8]").css({"padding":"0","border-top-width":"0"});
$(".accordion").css("border-width","0");
$(".pg-margin-auto").css({"margin":"0 auto"});
$(".tab2").css({"margin-top": "0", "margin-bottom": "0" });
$(".tab2 td").css({"border-left": "0"});
$("#dataTable td").css({"border-left": "0"});
$(".spanId").css({"color":"#ffd700"});
$(".table .td").css({"vertical-align":"middle"})

    var mydata = [
                    {
                     "item": "V400091-Amber Bottle Clear",
                     "vendor": "Alpha Packaging",
                     "vendor_location": "St. Louis, Mo",
                     "BU": 23,
                     "min_cost":"$0.06",
                     "avg_cost":"$0.09",
                     "max_cost":"$0.14",
                     "total_quantity_sold": "80,000,000",
                    },
                    {
                    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
                    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
                    "BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06",
                    "avg_cost":"$0.06",
                    "max_cost":"$0.06",
                    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
                    "inner_data":[{"vendor_name": "Silgan",
                                    "location": "Aurora, IL",
                                    "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
                                    "total_unit_purchased":"$0.06",
                                    "product_info":[{"business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
                                                     "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                                                     "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                                                     "total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017",
                                                     "average_unit_cost":"$0.14"},
                                                    {"Business Unit": "02-Dailas","berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09","total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017","average_unit_cost":"$0.14"}
                                                  ]},

                                  {"vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging","location": "Aurora, IL","last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018","total_unit_purchased":"$0.06"},
             ],

                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
"inner_data":[{"vendor_name": "Berlin",
                                    "location": "Aurora, IL",
                                    "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
                                    "total_unit_purchased":"$0.06",
                                    "product_info":[{"business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
                                                     "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                                                     "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                                                     "total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017",
                                                     "average_unit_cost":"$0.14"},
                                                    {"Business Unit": "02-Dailas","berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09","total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017","average_unit_cost":"$0.14"}
                                                  ]},
              {"vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging","location": "Aurora, IL","last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018","total_unit_purchased":"$0.06"},
             ],
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
"inner_data":[{"vendor_name": "Silgan",
                                    "location": "Aurora, IL",
                                    "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
                                    "total_unit_purchased":"$0.06",
                                    "product_info":[{"business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
                                                     "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                                                     "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                                                     "total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017",
                                                     "average_unit_cost":"$0.14"},
                                                    {"Business Unit": "02-Dailas","berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09","total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017","average_unit_cost":"$0.14"}
                                                  ]},
              {"vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging","location": "Aurora, IL","last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018","total_unit_purchased":"$0.06"},
             ],
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
"inner_data":[{"vendor_name": "Silgan",
                                    "location": "Aurora, IL",
                                    "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
                                    "total_unit_purchased":"$0.06",
                                    "product_info":[{"business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
                                                     "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                                                     "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                                                     "total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017",
                                                     "average_unit_cost":"$0.14"},
                                                    {"Business Unit": "02-Dailas","berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09","total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017","average_unit_cost":"$0.14"}
                                                  ]},
              {"vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging","location": "Aurora, IL","last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018","total_unit_purchased":"$0.06"},
             ],
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
"inner_data":[{"vendor_name": "Silgan",
                                    "location": "Aurora, IL",
                                    "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
                                    "total_unit_purchased":"$0.06",
                                    "product_info":[{"business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
                                                     "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                                                     "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                                                     "total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017",
                                                     "average_unit_cost":"$0.14"},
                                                    {"Business Unit": "02-Dailas","berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09","total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017","average_unit_cost":"$0.14"}
                                                  ]},
              {"vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging","location": "Aurora, IL","last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018","total_unit_purchased":"$0.06"},
             ],
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",

                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",

                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "Bottle","vendor": "Pune","vendor_location": "NYC","BU": 13692,"min_cost":4000,"avg_cost":6000,"max_cost":8000,"total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
"inner_data":[  {"vendor_name": "Silgan",
                "location": "Aurora, IL",
                "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
                "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06",
                "product_info": [
                    {
                        "business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
                        "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                        "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                        "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
                        "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
                    },
                    {
                        "business_unit": "02-Dailas",
                        "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                        "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                        "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
                        "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
                    },
                    {
                        "business_unit": "23-Lock Port",
                        "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                        "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                        "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
                        "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
                    }] 

                },
              {"vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging","location": "Aurora, IL","last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018","total_unit_purchased":"$0.06"},
              {"vendor_name": "Berry Plastic","location": "Aurora, IL","last_purchase_date": "February 20, 2018","total_unit_purchased":"$0.06"},

             ]    
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
"inner_data":[{"vendor_name": "Berlin",
                                    "location": "Aurora, IL",
                                    "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
                                    "total_unit_purchased":"$0.06",
                                    "product_info":[{"business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
                                                     "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
                                                     "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
                                                     "total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017",
                                                     "average_unit_cost":"$0.14"},
                                                    {"Business Unit": "02-Dailas","berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09","total_unit_purchased":"June 21,2017","average_unit_cost":"$0.14"}
                                                  ]},
              {"vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging","location": "Aurora, IL","last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018","total_unit_purchased":"$0.06"},
             ],
                    },
                    {
"item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML","vendor": "Berry Plastic","vendor_location": "Aurora, IL","BU": 23,"min_cost":"$0.06","avg_cost":"$0.06","max_cost":"$0.06","total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
                    },
                    {
                     "item": "Glass",
                     "vendor": "Pune",
                     "vendor_location": "NYC",
                     "BU": 13692,
                     "min_cost":4000,
                     "avg_cost":6000,
                     "max_cost":8000,
                     "total_quantity_sold": 500,
                    },                    
                ]


  $(function() 
  {

  var totRows=mydata.length;
   console.log(totRows);
   var table_body='<tbody>';
   for(i=0;i<totRows;i++)
   {


// This is main table

     table_body += `<tr id="td1" >
                        <td>
                        <a>
                            <span class="spanId"class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordionExample" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#innertable">&#8314;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">${mydata[i]["item"]}</a>
                            </td>
                        <td><a href="#">${mydata[i]["vendor"]}</a></td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["vendor_location"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["BU"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["min_cost"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["avg_cost"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["max_cost"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["total_quantity_sold"]}</td>
                      </tr>`
    //This is Table inside table

    if(mydata[i].inner_data)
   {      
     var len=mydata[i].inner_data.length;

    table_body+=`<tr id="innerrow"class="collapse show">
    <td colspan="8"><table class="table table-hover" id="innertable">
    <thead><tr>
    <th scope="col">Vendor Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Location</th>
    <th scope="col">Last Purchase Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Total Unit Purchased</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>`
     for(var j=0;j<len;j++)  
     { 
    table_body +=`<tr>
        <td>
        <a><span class="spanId"class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordionExample" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#producttable">&#8314;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a><a href="#">${mydata[i].inner_data[j].vendor_name}</a>
        </td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].location}</td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].last_purchase_date}</td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].total_unit_purchased}</td>
      </tr>`;




// This is Table inside inner table


if(mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info)
   {      
     var len1=mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info.length;

    table_body += `<tr id="productinfo"class="collapse show" >
    <td colspan="8">
   <table class="table table-hover" id="producttable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">Business Unit</th>
        <th scope="col">Berlin Item</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Purchase</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Unit Purchased</th>
        <th scope="col">Average Unit Cost</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>`
     for(var k=0;k<len1;k++)  
     { 
    table_body +=`<tr>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].business_unit}</td>
      <td><a href="#">${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].berlin_item}</a></td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].last_purchase}</td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].total_unit_purchased}</td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].average_unit_cost}</td>
      </tr>`;
     }
     table_body +='</tbody></table></td></tr>';
   }
}
table_body +='</tbody></table></td></tr>';

   } 
   }
   table_body+='</tbody>';
   $('#dataTable').append(table_body);

 $('td > a').on('click', function() {

  $(this).closest('tr').next().find('table:first').toggle();
});

    var table='#dataTable'
    var maxRows=20
    var totalRows=$(table+' tbody tr').length
    if(totalRows > maxRows)
    {      
        $(table+' tr:gt(28)').hide();
        var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows/maxRows)
        for(var i=1;i<=pagenum;)
        {
            $('.pagination').append('<li class="page-item" data-page="'+i+'">\<a class="page-link">'+ i++ +'<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>\</li>').show();
        }
    }
    $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active')
    $('.pagination li').on('click',function()
    {
        var pageNum=$(this).attr('data-page')
        var trIndex=0;
        $('.pagination li').removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass('active')
        $(table+' tr:gt(0)').each(function()
        {    
           trIndex++
            if(trIndex > (maxRows*pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows*pageNum)-maxRows))
            {
                $(this).hide()
               $('table table tr').show();
            } 
            else
            {
                $(this).show()
            }
        });
    });

  });

    </script>
```

Expected output:

1. Each page 10 Parent row with inner data
2. Parent row Expand and Collapse Particular

Comment: Btw when inspecting your table you duplicate `ID` a lot, keep in mind that you should not have multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: ignore that duplicate ..